# Inverse of $x\exp(-x)$

Tags: logarithms, lambert-w

What would be the inverse of the function $y=x\exp(-x)$ when $1\leq x\leq \infty$ and $0\leq y\leq 1/e$.

I tried to solve this with Lambert W function and the solution came out to be $-W(-y)$. But [in this paper (just above section 2 Application)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf) it is mentioned that the principle branch of the Lambert W function can not have a value lower than $-1$. Whereas for my problem the value of $W$ is starting from $-1$ and going down to $-\infty$.

So I am not sure whether my calculation is correct.

Comment: Since $-y=-x e^{-x}$ and $-x \leq -1$, I would say that we have to invert with the $W_{-1}$ branch, so $-x = W_{-1}(-y)$ and $x = -W_{-1}(-y)$, with a $y$ in the $(0,\frac{+1}{e}]$ interval.

Comment: Thank you. But $W_{-1}$ has a singularity at $y=0$, so what would be the behaviour of the function at $y=0$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by $1 \ge x \ge \infty$? How can $\infty$ be less than $1$? Same with $0 \ge 1/e$.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. It has been corrected. Thanks for pointing out @Gary

Comment: The comment by Loutcho Glotuk is correct. The inverse is $x=x(y)=-W_{-1}(-y)$. The behaviour near the singularity $y=0$ is $$
x = x(y) = \log (1/y) + \log \log (1/y) + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\log \log (1/y)}}{{\log (1/y)}}} \right)
$$ (cf. http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.13.E11).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So lets say I have an integration as $\int_0^1 x(k) dk$, where  $x(y)=-W_{-1}(-y)$. How would I proceed as $W_{-1}(0)$ has a singularity.

Comment: The singularity is integrable (it is like a $\log$). You can also make a change of variables $k=t e^{-t}$. Note that you can integrate up to $1/e$ only and not $1$. Thus $$
\int_0^{1/e} {x(k)dk}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {t(t - 1)e^{ - t} dt}=3/e .
$$

Comment: Two confusions. 
1. Why cant I integrate upto 1?  As for me $1\leq x \leq \infty$
2. Does $W_{-1}(-xe^{-x})$ give $-x$ same as $W_0(xe^{x})=x$ ?

Comment: Because $x(k)$ is defined for $0<k\le 1/e$ and you integrate with respect to $k$. Yes, $x(t e^{-t})=-W_{-1}(-t e^{-t})=--t=t$.

Comment: @Gary in the integration when you substitute $k=te^{-t}$ shouldn't the upper limit of the integration becomes 1 instead of $+\infty$ ( $1/e = te^{-t} \implies t=1$) ? And also with the  $0$ to $\infty$ limit the answer came 1.

Comment: For $k=0$, $t$ has to tend to $+\infty$ so that $t e^{-t} \to 0$. For $k=1/e$, $t$ should be $1$. Thus we have $$
\int_0^{1/e} {x(k)dk}  = \int_{ + \infty }^1 {t(1 - t)e^{ - t} dt}  = \int_1^{ + \infty } {t(t - 1)e^{ - t} dt}  = 3/e.
$$ I just mistyped that lower limit in my previous answer.

Comment: For $k=0$ can't we say that $t=0$ as $0\times e^0 =0$ ?

Comment: Didn't we agree that $x(k)$ blows up at $k=0$ like a $\log$? Just draw a picture and interpret the integral as the area under the curve and rotate the picture.

Comment: So that means you are not making $k=0$ to get $t=\infty$ you are getting $t\rightarrow\infty$ by making $k\rightarrow 0$ as at $k=0$ the function does not exist.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thank you very much @Gary for the clarifications.